# How to place String drawn by Graphics on top of an oval in java

Tags: java, string, graphics

I need to write a `String` over an oval, so the oval has the text showing up in the middle of it. The text is drawn by `g.drawString();` method, and the oval by `g.fillOval();`. How is it possible to place the `String` on top?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you for instance check the Swing tutorials? (assuming you are using Swing, of course)

Comment: I searched for ages on google but found nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                // Some parameters.
                String text = "Some Label";
                int centerX = 150, centerY = 100;
                int ovalWidth = 200, ovalHeight = 100;

                // Draw oval
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillOval(centerX-ovalWidth/2, centerY-ovalHeight/2,
                           ovalWidth, ovalHeight);

                // Draw centered text
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                double textWidth = fm.getStringBounds(text, g).getWidth();
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawString(text, (int) (centerX - textWidth/2),
                                   (int) (centerY + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2));

            }
        });

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```